# How to present a list in views for this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view

I want to present products based on a user attribute. So basically I'm retrieving an object from product class based on user attribute. I don't know how to create a list in my views for those. How can I present them by an attribute? These are my views below right now where I'm showing all products:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
      <%= render "product_row", product: product, order_item: @order_item %>
    <% end %>
```

My user.rb

```
def products_for_gender
    if gender == 'male'
      Product.where("product_id: '9'")
    elsif gender == 'female'
      Product.where("product_id: '10'")
    else
      Product.where("product_id: '11'")
    end
  end
```

And my controller:

```
def index
    @products = Product.all
    @products = current_user.products_for_gender
    @order_item = current_order.order_items.new
  end
```

Right now I'm getting this error when I try to access product views:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Products#index
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/products/index.html.erb where line #31 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: ":": SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."active" = ? AND (product_id: '9')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your `.where()` query:

```
Product.where("product_id: '9'")
```

This should be:

```
Product.where("product_id = 9")
# or even better:
Product.where(product_id: 9)
```

**Update:** (per author comments)

```
Product.where(id: 9)
# or, if you want to make sure the products exist
Product.find(9)
```

Comment: Still getting the same error on the line 31:     <% @products.each do |product| %>

Comment: Did you fix all of your `where()` queries?

Comment: yes I have.. Actually it's not the same error now I get this error when I try to view product view: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Products#index
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/products/index.html.erb where line #31 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: products.product_id: SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."active" = ? AND "products"."product_id" = 9

Comment: I guess you want to find product by its `id`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hmm now I'm getting a new error undefined method "each" on line 31:  <% @products.each do |product| %>

Comment: sorry! it works now with Product.where(id: 9)    thank you!! :)